# Scala actor call an actor trouble

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I start work with akka actors, and write code, what works, but not exactly how i expect:

```
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
import org.bson.types.ObjectId
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.UTC
import com.mongodb.casbah.commons.conversions.scala._
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.Props



object Commands{
  case class GetActivities(uid: String)
  case class GetIds(activities: Iterable[DBObject])
  case class GetDataForIds(data: Map[String, List[ObjectId]])

}

class Commands extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Commands.GetActivities(uid) =>
      sender ! Commands.GetActivities(uid)
    case Commands.GetIds(activities) =>
      sender ! Commands.GetIds(activities)
    case Commands.GetDataForIds(data) =>
      sender ! Commands.GetDataForIds(data)
  }
}

class Activities extends Actor{

  override def preStart(): Unit = {

    val commands = context.actorOf(Props[Commands], "commands")

    commands ! Commands.GetActivities("53f76b6553544244db060000")
  }

  def receive = {
    case Commands.GetActivities(uid) => {
      println(get(uid))
      println("get activities")
      println("------------")
      sender ! Commands.getIds(get(uid))
    }
  }
  def get(userId: String): Iterable[DBObject] ={}
}

class Ids() extends Actor{
  def receive = {
    case Commands.GetIds(activities) => {
      println(getIds(activities))
      println("get ids")
      println("------------")
      sender ! Commands.GetDataForIds(getIds(activities))
    }
  }
  def getIds(activities: Iterable[DBObject]): Map[String, List[ObjectId]] =
}

class DataForIds() extends Actor{
  def receive = {
    case Commands.GetDataForIds(activities) => println(getDataForIds(activities))
  }

  def getDataForIds(data: Map[String, List[ObjectId]]): Map[String, Any] = {}

object Driver {

  def main{
    val system = ActorSystem("Main")
    val ac = system.actorOf(Props[Activities])
  }

}
```

When i compile and run Driver.main - i get only

```
println(get(uid))
println("get activities")
println("------------")
```

And process looks like freeze didnt END without CTRL+C

But i want in `Activities` in `case Commands.GetActivities(uid)`  after running function `get(uid)`  start actor `Ids` - what i do wrong?
Concept is `Ids.getIds( Activities.get(uid) )`

Comment: First of all.... please and please don't use names starting with small letters for any `case class`.

Comment: ty for syntax correct, changed my code and edited question

Comment: And... I dont find anything wrong with your code. You are not handling any message of type `GetDataForIds` in your `Activites` actor. So the reply from `Commands` actor is ignored by your `Activities` actor.

Comment: Also... this - `sender ! Commands.GetDataForIds(GetIds(activities))` should be `sender ! Commands.GetDataForIds( getIds( activities ) )`

Comment: just add handler for `Commands.GetDataForIds` type messages in your `Activities` actor.

Comment: i have class DataForIds (now add to question) - but my problem - in Class Activities, after println("-------") my console just stop, without stopping, or exit - just freeze, and i dont get println(getIds(activities))   from class Ids.

Comment: it looks that https://www.dropbox.com/s/7hgr51cwv1eqvqi/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202015-03-17%2017.30.57.png?dl=0

Comment: What does it mean - handler in activities? it looks like?

Comment: Because here - `println("------------"); sender ! Commands.getIds(get(uid))`, `sender` is the one who sent the message i.e. - `command` actor, so you are sending it to `command` actor. You need to create an instance of your `Ids` actor and send to it.

Comment: oh, get it, but when i have to redirect my call from Activities -> Commands -> Activities to Activities -> Commands -> Ids

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73171/discussion-between-legendary-and-sarvesh-kumar-singh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HUGE thanks to  @Sarvesh-Kumar-Singh, and that the answer

```
class Commands extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Commands.GetActivities(uid) =>
      sender ! Commands.GetActivities(uid)
    case Commands.GetIds(activities) =>
      val ids = context.actorOf(Props[Ids], "ids")
      ids ! Commands.GetIds(activities)
    case Commands.GetDataForIds(data) =>
      val dataforids = context.actorOf(Props[DataForIds], "daraforids")
      dataforids ! Commands.GetDataForIds(data)
  }
}
```